# Is there a way to locate a TCP Server running under local network?

Tags: c#, sockets, networking

Is there a way to locate a TCP Server running under local network using raw sockets and C#?

-The Client searching for the Server is running under the same local network as the Server and it knows the port the Server is running with.

-is it by Broadcast?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible to do this with the [Socket](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx) class if the server sends UDP broadcasts on a periodic basis or in response to a solicitation. The client would have to listen for UDP broadcasts and optionally send a solicitation to discover the server.

- MSDN: [Using UDP Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tst0kwb1.aspx)

---

If you're not strictly limited to the Socket class, have a look at [DNS-SD](http://www.dns-sd.org/) / [Zero configuration networking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_configuration_networking). This has been invented for the exact purpose of discovering services on a local network.